# How to format a string with a custom dynamic format

Tags: c#, .net, string, string-formatting

I know that `string.Format` and `ToString()` can apply formatting to a string,

In my case i have a string with the value (typically it will have a string representation of a data but can have string representations of other base datatypes) and i have another string that represents the desired format. These values are coming from a database, what i need is to apply one to the other

I'm not even sure this is possible at all, so any pointers are welcome. I haven't been able to apply any version of ToString or Format. because these require that you declare on the spot what format you want and mine are dynamic

Is there some formatting method like the tryParse (in the sense that it would try any possible formatting for the data it is given?

EDIT: some examples as requested:

```
 stringInput = "Jan 31 2012"; //string representation of a date
 inputFormat="dd/MM/yyyy, HH mm"
 outputString = "31/Jan/2015, 00:00";

 stringInput = "100"; //string representation of a number
 inputFormat="D6"
 outputString = "000100";
```

Comment: question will be more clear if you add examples of values and formats

Comment: Gives us some data examples

Comment: *"because these require that you declare on the spot what format you want and mine are dynamic"* Not really, they take a string, it doesn't have to be defined inline, `string.Format(formatFromDb, valueFromDb)` should work just fine.

Comment: Taking the time to write this question made me realize that my problem was that i was trying to format strings which really wont lead me anywhere.

If i back-convert the string to its original data type then i can ToString them and have my correct output. Ill accept an answer that validates this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string.Format(string, string)` takes 2 string arguments so you can take them from db and apply them directly:

```
string formatToApply = "{0} and some text and then the {1}";
string firstText = "Text";
string secondText = "finsh.";

// suppose that those strings are from db, not declared locally
var finalString = string.Format(formatToApply, firstText, secondText);
// finalString = "Text and some text and then the finish."
```

However, there is a great risk to have wrong number of specifiers or wrong number of arguments. If you have a call like this, it will throw an exception:

```
var finalString = string.Format(formatToApply, firstText);
//An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll; 
//Additional information: Index (zero based) must be greater than or 
//equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
```

So wrap your call into a `try/catch/ (maybe) finally` to handle this situation accordingly to your needs.

**Later Edit after desired examples were posted:**

First example: you might want to take advantage of DateTime class from C# which knows to format its output values. So you need first to convert `stringInput` into a DateTime:

```
var inputDateTime = DateTime.Parse(stringInput);
var outputString = inputDateTime.ToString(inputFormat);
```

Second example: again, you might want to take advantage of Double class and conversion occurs again:

```
var inputDouble = Double.Parse(stringInput);
var outputString = inputDouble.ToString(inputFormat);
```

In summary of those two examples, you need to know the **type** of input string, type which you specified in your comments ("string representation of a date"). Knowing this you can take advantage of each specific class and its ability to format output strings. Otherwise it would be difficult to design yourself some kind of general formatter. A simple method might look like this:

```
public string GetFormattedString(string inputString, string inputFormat, string type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case "double":
            var inputDouble = Double.Parse(inputString);
            return inputDouble.ToString(inputFormat);
            break;
        case "datetime":
            var inputDateTime = DateTime.Parse(inputString);
            return inputDateTime.ToString(inputFormat);
            break;
        case "...": // other types which you need to support
        default: throw new ArgumentException("Type not supported: " + type);
    }
}
```

This `switch` is only an idea of how the logic may occur but you will need to handle errors for `Parse` methods and for `ToString` methods and if you have many types to support is better to take advantage of some design patterns like `Factory`.

Comment: Your example doesn't really format the string, more like concatenates them. for what i want, {1} would be a format string (and not a regular string).

I added two output examples, please look at them

Comment: I edited the answer accordingly to your examples, also matching your thoughts about converting back to data types and then again into strings.